# How to add a symbol next to an enumerated item?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, bclogo

How could I add a symbol from `bclogo` next to an enumerated item like in the picture?
[image]

Comment: With ˙\marginpar{...}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assumption is that you only want some items to have a bomb next to them. So, create a `\bombitem` that adapts to the `enumerate` level:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bclogo,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bombitem}{%
  \refstepcounter{\@enumctr}% step the level-specific counter
  \item[% Insert item/enumeration
    {\raisebox{-.7ex}[0pt][0pt]{\scalebox{.5}{\bcbombe}}}% Place bomb
    \,% Space
    \@nameuse{label\@enumctr}]% Place level-formatted counter
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \bombitem Third item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \bombitem Third item
    \item Last item
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The above assumes you'll use `\bombitem` inside an `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bclogo}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\raisebox{-1em}[0em][0em]{\bcbombe}\ \theenumi.}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
\item bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

One can do the same with `\labelenumii` for second level.

**Update** to do this localy, Two methodes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bclogo}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
{\renewcommand\labelenumi{\raisebox{-1em}[0em][0em]{\bcbombe}\ \theenumi.}
\item bla bla}
\item bla
\item[\mbox{\refstepcounter{enumi}\raisebox{-1em}[0em][0em]{\bcbombe}\ \theenumi.}]
bla bla
\item bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want it only in the second item?

Comment: @giannis see update.

Comment: How about  cross-references to bomb items?

Comment: @Bernard with second method no problem