# Customized Biblatex styles to include numbered index + icon on bib

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, biber, moderncv

Using the moderncv + biblatex, I created the list of publications with label prefix and index number.
For a specific index, I would like to include an image/icon at the bottom of the label index as shown below:

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way or reference to generate such customized Biblatex styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bibliography items are very short, an icon placed below the label number may clash with the label number of the next item. So I suggest to place the icon to the left of the label, together with the code from [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123809/35864) to [Creating bibliographies with biblatex and moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123805/35864) for better `moderncv` compatibility of the bibliography environment there is ample space there.

The icon can be taken from `fontawesome5` and can be positioned with `\raisebox` (that bit of code is inspired by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292634/35864) to [How to add a symbol next to an enumerated item?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292623/35864)) and a sprinkle of `\hspace`.

There are many possible ways to tell `biblatex` which entries are supposed to be shown with an icon. The biggest question is whether you want to tell `biblatex` about the icon in the `.bib` file or in the `.tex` file.

#### Set icon from the `.bib` file: `options`

Here I used entry options from the `.bib` entry, but the same principle could be applied with categories (see below).

```
\documentclass[british]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\newcommand*{\printmedalicon}{%
  \raisebox{-1pt}[0pt][0pt]{\faIcon{medal}\hspace{1em}}}

\newtoggle{bbx:showicon}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{showicon}{\settoggle{bbx:showicon}{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{showmedalicon}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:showicon}
    {\printmedalicon}
    {}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\usebibmacro{showmedalicon}%
      \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}
\firstname{Jane}
\familyname{Doe}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
  options = {showicon},
}
@book{elk,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1972},
  options = {showicon},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,aksin,appleby,elk}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography: Two items have a medal icon on the left]

#### Set icon from the `.tex` file: Categories

```
\documentclass[british]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\newcommand*{\printmedalicon}{%
  \raisebox{-1pt}[0pt][0pt]{\faIcon{medal}\hspace{1em}}}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{showicon}

\newbibmacro*{showmedalicon}{%
  \ifcategory{showicon}
    {\printmedalicon}
    {}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\usebibmacro{showmedalicon}%
      \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}
\firstname{Jane}
\familyname{Doe}


\addtocategory{showicon}{sigfridsson,nussbaum}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,aksin,worman,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with medal icons]

Comment: Thank you for the response. It worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to adapt the `begentry` bibmacro to display the icon in the left margin. I haven’t tested this with numerical bibliography styles, but it works with author–year styles.

More precisely, I use it to include icons that are linked to DOIs and URLs (inspired by the *American Economic Review*):

```
% !BIB program = biber

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, urlcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend = biber, bibstyle = authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \hspace{-1.67em}% Protrude into left margin
    \makebox[1.67em][l]{%
        \iffieldundef{doi}{% Check if DOI provided
            % DOI not provided:
            \iffieldundef{url}{% Check if URL provided
                % URL not provided: Print nothing
            }{%
                % URL provided:
                \href{%
                    \thefield{url}% Link to URL
                }{%
                    \raisebox{0.1ex}{\footnotesize\faIcon{external-link-alt}}% Print icon
                }
            }
        }{%
            % DOI provided:
            \href{%
                https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}% Link to DOI website
            }{%
                \raisebox{0.067ex}{\small\faIcon[regular]{file-alt}}% Print icon 
            }%
        }%
    }%
}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{}  % Suppress output of DOI
%\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{}  % Suppress output of URL
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{markey, nussbaum, sigfridsson, worman}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output with icons and DOI/URL]

If you consider printing the DOI and URL unnecessary, you can suppress output of these fields via

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{}  % Suppress output of DOI
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{}  % Suppress output of URL
```

This makes the bibliography less cluttered:

[image: Output with icons and without DOI/URL]

Comment: Thanks for this well-documented and easy-to-follow example!
My document uses numeric citation style, and I found that works too, just requires a little horizontal adjustments. But in the end I simply replaced `begentry` with `finentry` and let the icon show after `\finentry`. I would never have figured this out without your example :-)
Can't post code here, so I posted my version on my linkblog https://links.solarchemist.se/shaare/iyy4lQ